# Create incident in dynamics crm using api in php

Tags: php, api, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics, navigation-properties

Im trying to create case in dynamics CRM using php.For that I can see that title,description and customer is required.So that I tried below code:

```
  $authHeader = 'Authorization:' . $type.' '.$access_token;
    //Request for incidents
  $data = array("title"=>"api_incident_title",
            "description" =>"api_incident_description",
    "primaryContactid" =>"https://vonageholdings.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.0/accounts(ebaf25a6-f131-e611-80f8-c4346bac3990)"
        );
    //URL
    $url ='https://vonageholdings.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.0/incidents';
    //request for incidents
    $data_string = json_encode($data);
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($authHeader,
            'Content-Type:application/json','Accept:application/json;'));
```

It's showing **"code":"","message":"You should specify a parent contact or account."** Im trying to use navigation property.But I can't find the exact `property` to send `customerId`.

I have tried with following links:
[link1](http://crmtroubleshoot.blogspot.in/2013/07/dynamics-crm-2011-php-and-soap-calls.html)[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751754/how-to-create-a-case-incident-in-microsoft-crm-using-the-php-webservice)[link3](http://%20https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt593043.aspx#bkmk_SingleValuedNavigationProperties)

I'm trying for a long time.It's too frustrated.

After I tried @Alex comment,I referred [create incidents](https://mscrmcodesamples.wordpress.com/2016/04/11/create-record-using-web-api-ms-crm-2016/) with following request,

```
$data = array('primarycontactid@odata.bind' =>"https://xxxx.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.0/contacts(4bafdfb0-08d7-e511-80eb-c4346bac3990)",
        'incident_customer_accounts'=>array("title"=>"case_account","description" =>"case")
        );
```

It shows `A node of type 'StartObject' was read from the JSON reader when trying to read the contents of the navigation property 'incident_customer_accounts'; however, a 'StartArray' node was expected.` this error.

Now I think our request is correct but format is mismatching.

Comment: Your last error (" A node of type ...") looks like an issue with how the data is structured VS what JSONReader expects, I'd move that to a question of its own dedicated to it

Comment: Yes @Alex.Need help for this. what structure to use to post data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally case is create using below request in php

```
$data = array("title"=>"test",
        "description" =>"case",
        "customerid_contact@odata.bind" =>"/contacts(c18df8d6-74d9-e511-80eb-c4346bac3990)"
        );

 $url ='https://yyyyy.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.0/incidents';
```

Answer (score 1):

**Associate entities on create**

To associate new entities to existing entities when they are created you must set the value of single-valued navigation properties using the `@odata.bind` annotation.

The following request body posted to the accounts entity set will create a new account associated with an existing contact with the contactid value of 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001.

**Request**

```
POST [Organization URI]/api/data/v8.2/accounts HTTP/1.1

Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

OData-MaxVersion: 4.0

OData-Version: 4.0

Accept: application/json

{
"name":"Sample Account",

"primarycontactid@odata.bind":"/contacts(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001)"
}
```

**Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content

OData-Version: 4.0

OData-EntityId: [Organization URI]/api/data/v8.2/accounts(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002)
```

[Create an entity using WebAPI - MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328090.aspx#bkmk_associateOnCreate)

Comment: Thanks @Alex.Actually i already tried this one.But it shows 
`[16] =>   "error":{[17] =>     "code":"","message":"An unexpected error occurred.","innererror"` error.
Also i need to create a new incident(CASE) through API. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334767.aspx#bkmk_lookupProperty have some incidents properties, but it for retrieve incidents. I need proper navigation property to create incident.

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about PHP, except a lot of people use it.  Have you checked out [Alexa CRM](https://alexacrm.com/toolkit/)?  They have a php toolkit to simply connecting to, and interacting with CRM and PHP.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Daryl.I want a sample post params and navigation property for creating cases. I'm using `Advance REST client API` to test api's.