# How to update a contact in Dynamics365 using AlexaCRM php-crm-toolkit

Tags: php, dynamics-crm

I am trying to update a contact in Dynamics365 using PHP CRM toolkit https://github.com/AlexaCRM/php-crm-toolkit, I don't understand what does 'guid' represents here?

```php
$contact = $service->entity( 'contact', $guid );
```

Also where can I find a list of 'FieldNames' so that I can create a new contact/account?

Comment: Pls read online tutorials. Start with https://stackoverflow.com/q/42501267/7920473

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the field names go to Sales dropdown, select Settings, customizations, Customize the system, a new window will pop up, from the left side of new this window choose Entities->Account(Or any module you want)->Fields. On the right side you will get a list of field names with there details.

Answer (score 1):

Your code **gets one record** from database by its ID. Parameters are name of entity (table) and its GUID. The code in the tutorial is not correct. It should be:

```php
$contactId = '1d2fc62f-1c56-448b-b546-edfb6d6fec5c';
$contact = $service->entity( 'contact', $contactId );
```

---

### What is GUID?

1. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)
2. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/system.guid(v=vs.110).aspx)
3. [How to get it in CRM](https://arunpotti.wordpress.com/2016/07/10/how-to-get-guid-of-the-record-in-crm-online/)

---

### What are the fields/attributes?

1. Download [SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh547453.aspx), there is file EntityMetadata.xlsx with page Attributes.
2. Or (shorter), in CRM UI, open Advanced Search, choose entity and click Add columns and Add columns again. You will see system names of attributes as well.

Comment: What happens if I don't have the GUID, but an email or my own ID field instead? How can I then update an entity?